How to properly type useGetters from vuex-composition-helpers
I'm rewriting old code and want to make vuex-composition-helpers useGetters typesafe. I don't want to move to Pinia yet.
This is the single example I could find:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-composition-helpers#typescript-mappings
import { GetterTree } from "vuex"; // not in the example
import { useGetters } from "vuex-composition-helpers"; // not in the example

interface RootGetters extends GetterTree<any, any> {
    article: string;
    comments: string;
}
...
const { article, comments } = useGetters<RootGetters>(['article', 'comments']);

The above example throws an error in the interface definition

Property 'article' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Getter<any, any>' ts(2411)

It seems to me the example is wrong, but everyone is quoting it. What am I missing?

to be precise, it does do something: useGetters<RootGetters>(['foobar']) properly gives an error. But typescript thinks useGetters<RootGetters>(['article']) is a ref to a variable of type <any>

I think the example should say article: (state: State) => string; instead of article: string;. That makes sense, and it works (I think)
